# Read text into C. Get a bad exec error

Tags: c

Trying to learn C. Want to read the first line of a text file, my code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    FILE *in = fopen("test.txt", "rt");
    // read the first line from the file
    char buffer[100];
    fgets(buffer, 20, in);
    printf("first line of \"test.txt\": %s\n", buffer);
    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm doing this in xCode. I get a exc bad access error.
test.txt definitely exists. It has one line that says "this is a text file"

Comment: Check return value from `fopen()`. Just because it exists does not guarantee that the attempt to open will succeed.

Comment: It sounds like `fopen()` is not succeeding.  Make sure its return value isn't a null pointer before doing something with it.  If it is a null pointer, there may be a file permission issue.

Comment: I think the t is for text..."read text" but I don't know I just found that code online. The problem was that the program isn't run in the same directory as @zvrba mentioned. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks fine, so my guess is that the program is not run in the same working directory as the file.  Try placing the file in, say, `/tmp/test.txt` and use absolute path in `fopen`.

Answer (score 1):

try this after `fopen()` call:

```
if(in == NULL){
    printf("Can't read teste.txt because: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
 }
```

and add the headers:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't check if the `FILE` is NULL. It may not be opened for a several reasons.